# Div lateral overflow with others divs inside

Tags: html, scroll, scrollbar

I have the:

```
.events-cont {
    width:100%;
    height:250px;
    overflow:scroll;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:20px;
    display:block
}

.events {
    width:210px;
    height:250px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0 10px;
    padding:0;
    border-right:3px #666 solid;
}
```

And I want a lateral scroll of manys .events divs repeatedly like the img in the link.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEyrY.jpg: